# Chrome request not making it to server

Tags: google-chrome, iis

I have a Windows 2016 Server with IIS 10.0.14393.0 installed that is maintained within an isolated VM environment. (The entire VM environment is isolated from the real-world.)

The web server is configured with three websites through IIS, and each website is assigned a dedicated IP. The contents in each of these websites is a single "hello world" html page that can be accessed via a browser from from my development workstation using Microsoft Edge, but I cannot access these pages using Chrome. The simple hello world html page was created only to assist in troubleshooting this issue.

The error received in Chrome is ERR_TIMED_OUT and based on the IIS logs, the request is never reaching the web server. IIS logs do indicate the request/reponse when accessing using Edge.

From my workstation, I can successfully ping the web server, traceroute output does not indicate any unexpected hops, etc.  From all indications, the problem appears to be isolated to Chrome and only when accessing the sites on that server.  I have other servers (W2016 and W2019) in the real-world with a similar configurations and real applications deployed there that work as expected with any browser.

I am using the latest Chrome Version 105.0.5195.102 (Official Build) (64-bit) and can access other web based content within this VM environment using Chrome, just not on that one server.

I am almost to the point of deleting that VM instance and starting over so any ideas/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Learn to use a tool like Wireshark to track down HTTP requests, and then you can focus on what is wrong with the packets sent by Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

> The error received in Chrome is ERR_TIMED_OUT

This is a communication problem indication that there is a problem with the user's local network connection. It can appear when your internet is too slow or your connection is taking too long, or the page or website you are visiting may be too busy, or when the website in question is not set up correctly, or even if the website is trying to perform more than your server can manage.

I'm not sure if you've seen the following methods, but you can try.

**Method 1: Browse in Incognito Mode and Remove Extensions.**

> You should first browse the website in incognito mode to check if you
> can open the website normally, if so then the culprit of the
> ERR_TIMED_OUT error may be your plugin or extension. Therefore, you
> need to enable extensions one by one to check for errors, and if there
> is an error enabling an extension, you need to remove it from your
> browser.

**Method 2: Delete the Default Chrome Folder**

> 1. Press Win + R keys at the same time to open the Run
> 2. Type %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\ in the box and click OK.
> 3. Close your Chrome if it is opened.
> 4. A new window pops out, find the folder named Default. Backup the folder anywhere else, then right-click the folder to choose Delete.
>
> After you have deleted the folder successfully, open your Chrome and
> then visit the webpage again that you searched before to check if the
> error still appears.

**Method 3: Update Network Drivers**

> If your network driver is out of date, you may encounter ERR_TIMED_OUT
> errors. Here's how to update network drivers.
>
> 1. Right-click the Start button to select Device Manager.
> 2. Scroll down to find Network Adapters and click on it to expand it.
> 3. Right-click on your network device and select Update Driver.
> 4. Select Search automatically for updated driver software option to start to search and update your network driver to a new version.
>
> After that, restart your computer and open the sites again with Chrome
> to see if you can open them.

**Method 4: Disable Firewall & Antivirus Software**

> Sometimes, your firewall or antivirus software may cause trouble.
> Therefore, you should try to disable them and check if the problem can
> be solved. If you find it helpful to disable these programs, you can
> check the firewall settings. Allow Chrome to connect to public or
> private networks. If it doesn't work. Permanently delete these
> programs, and then use other antivirus software or firewalls.

**Method 5: Check Hosts File**

> When you meet the ERR_TIMED_OUT error accessing a specific website,
> you can check the Hosts file to see if the website has been blocked.
> Here is the way to do that:
>
> 1. Press Win + E keys at the same time to open File Explorer and then go to the Local Disk C: > Windows > System32 > Drivers > etc.
> 2. Open the host file with notepad. If you see the web address that you cannot visit, delete that entire line from the host file and save.
>
> After that, open the Chrome and see if you can open the specific
> website.

**Method 6: Reinstall Chrome Browser**

> If none of the methods above fix the ERR_TIMED_OUT error, then you
> should try reinstalling Chrome. Here is the tutorial:
>
> 1. Press Win + R keys at the same time to open the Run box, then type appwiz.cpl and click OK to open a new window.
> 2. Find Google Chrome in the list, and then right-click it to choose Uninstall.
> 3. After uninstalling Google Chrome successfully, you also need to delete its leftover files. Open the Run box again, then type %appdata%
>    and click OK to open a new window.
> 4. Find the Google folder and then right-click it to choose Delete.
> 5. Go to Google Chrome’s site to download the latest version of the browser, and then install it.

The above methods are from the [web article](https://www.minitool.com/news/err-timed-out.html). To avoid link being unavailable, I have also presented the details. I am not sure if the above methods can help you, but I hope you can solve the problem soon.

Comment: I appreciate the information, but these were some of the very first steps I took in attempting to resolve this particular issue.

Comment: Well, maybe starting over will have a different outcome.